# "Pasto" vs. "césped" vs. "prado"

Tags: vocabulario, definiciones, significado, plantas

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "pasto", "césped" y "prado"?

¿Cuál palabra se usa para hablar acerca de las partes verdes en una ciudad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Veamos qué dice el DRAE:

> **[prado](http://dle.rae.es/?w=prado&o=h)**
>
> Del lat. pratum.
>
> 1. m. Tierra muy húmeda o de regadío, en la cual se deja crecer o se siembra la hierba para pasto de los ganados.
> 2. m. Sitio ameno que sirve de paseo en algunas poblaciones.
>
> **[césped](http://dle.rae.es/?w=c%C3%A9sped&o=h)**
>
> De céspede, y este del lat. caespes, -ĭtis.
>
> 1. m. Hierba menuda y tupida que cubre el suelo.
>
> ...
>
> 4. m. Dep. Terreno de juego con hierba.
>
> **[pasto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S6GrLPI%7CS6HgApw%7CS6HlWLD&o=h)**
>
> Del lat. pastus 'pastura'.
>
> 2. m. Hierba que el ganado pace en el mismo terreno donde se cría.
> 3. m. Cosa que sirve para el sustento del animal.
> 4. m. Sitio en que pasta el ganado. U. m. en pl. Galicia tiene buenos pastos.
>
> ...
>
> 8. m. Arg., Col., Méx. y Ur. césped (‖ hierba menuda).

Como se ve, pasto y césped son sinónimos en Argentina, Colombia y México. En ambos casos, se refiere a la hierba en sí, más que el lugar -a menos que sea para algo deportivo. Por otro lado, prado sí tiene la connotación de lugar (véase la acepción segunda).

Por tanto, yo usaría "prado" para referirme a la parte verde de una ciudad.

Comment: Buena reaspuesta. Para mi en Colombia todas son sinónimos y usaria indistintamente cualquiera.

Comment: Que interesante, en Argentina solo se dice pasto, rara vez césped, es más parecería que la palabra césped tiene un aire culto.

Ahora se que realmente la palabra correcta es césped, y no pasto. saludos.

Comment: @fedorqui, En México se le dice pasto también, al igual que en Argentina, como menciona *Lobo-Eze*. Prado me parece más un campo silvestre, quizá por que lo relaciono con *pradera*. De hecho, en las jardineras de las ciudades en México, es común ver letreros de "Prohibido pisar el pasto".

Comment: Césped no es la palabra "correcta" simplemente es una palabra diferente. En México igual decimos pasto, sólo son diferencias léxicas.

Comment: Según mi experiencia, en España usaríamos *césped* para referirnos a las partes verdes de una ciudad, entendiendo por tales las que hay en un parque o en los parterres de las calles. Un *prado* es una extensión grande, normalmente en el campo. Además, *césped* es incontable, por lo que sería *el césped*, nunca *un césped*, a menos que vayamos a usar algún calificativo (*este parque tiene un césped muy tupido*).

Answer (score 3):

En Perú, en el ambiente académico de la Universidad Nacional Agraria se manejan los siguientes conceptos:

1. Pasto: se refiere a las áreas en donde crecen las gramíneas que se emplean para el pastoreo o alimentación del ganado.
2. Prados: se refieren a los campos en donde se desarrollan las gramíneas en estado silvestre, regadas solo con agua de lluvia y que ocasionalmente se usa para pastoreo del ganado.
3. Césped: se refiere a los campos en donde se cultivan algunas gramíneas. Se debe entender por cultivar a las actividades de corte, riego y tratamiento de enfermedades, plagas y control de malezas. Un campo cubierto de césped puede ser utilizado para la práctica deportiva o para actividades de recreación.

Answer (score 2):

Pasto efectivamente es una planta. En México lo usamos para referirnos indistintamente a ella y al lugar que se genera cuando se siembra. 
En jardinería, un prado de pasto que se mantiene cuidado y recortado se considera césped.